# For a cipher school challenge I need help breaking this cipher

Tags: ciphers

[CIPHERTEXTSTARTS]HI wsndtonInehbihs if at t  iyoncniegtrf .e  noionbpni y,iu.w ahoui  hs hroyh!euecsy m.ot ew hrc hb;ntsresnmdma ipMsat ln  ts , ryiceg ensh  c  n byr  t k t  oe de uhw stiytoer s eevlde utln a lerytkhhte ae srdaBry,etyofattu.ttd t?ybor ubeusf elog oentiyrueeruuuemcndu ’naIlaow  ystal nta.mAy dt ddin aoa,’une yeof hct dsirnetso lruohwpo ctoioa oyif awtowsrdupttep nm aIraulnhiebW ynoi[CIPHERTEXTENDS]

Comment: While we are happy to help with homework or challenges, we will not just do the work for you. You need to at least attempt to answer the question yourself. Also, you have left out all context for this question, so I'm not sure how we can help.

Answer (score 5):

If I where you I would look at [Cryptanalysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptanalysis), in particular [letter frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_frequency). The idea of which, certain letters in English occur more regularly than others (e.g. vowels).